# Combobox not displaying correctly in android

Tags: android, livecode

I have a combobox that works fine in windows standalone, but in android the drop down covers the whole screen with the items on the top left hand corner.

What do I have to do to make the combobox drop box stay underneath it

This is the code behind the combobox

```
on textChanged

   put  the label of me into tlabel
   put me into tlist
   filter lines of tlist with tlabel into tfilter

   if tfilter=empty then 

      answer tlabel && "is not a valid entry." & return &  "You must enter M or F"
      undo

   else

      set the label of me to tfilter

      end if

end textChanged
```

Comment: Some bits of code would be nice.

Comment: Try using the wrap_content attrbute on your combo_box width and height in the layout file

Comment: @Sheils sorry to tell you that this is the correct way for LiveCode to display a combobox menu on Android. This is standard behaviour on Android. The GUI on Android should be completely different from the GUI on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a combobox, use a normal button with the following script:

```
on mouseUp
  put the text of btn "Your Old Combo Box" into myList
  if the cUsersChoice of me is an integer then
    put the cUsersChoice of me into myInitialChoice
  else put 0 into myInitialChoice
  mobilePick myList, myInitialChoice
  put the result into myUsersChoice
  if myUsersChoice is an integer and myUsersChoice > 0 then
    set the cUsersChoice of me to myUsersChoice
  end if
end mouseUp
```

This doesn't do exactly what you ask for, but it should look better on Android 4 and later. (It looks the same on Android 2 and I'm not sure about 3).

Comment: Hi Mark, I can see how this could work. Is there a way to dictate the size and position of the mobilepick. If it is possible to dictate that I can make the button small like the combobox button and then put a text entry field next to it and group them to looks like a conventional combobox. The mobile pickup would then have to appear just below the text entry field.

Comment: No, that's not possible and I would discourage using such GUI hacks. If you really want this, you could just use a list field and show and hide it like a menu.

Comment: Ok I will give that a go. Have to shot off to work now will get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: Mark following on your advise I have create a "combobox" by combining a button, text entry field and listbox and added codes in the button to show/hide the listbox. In the listbox I have added codes to enter the selected into the text entry field. I works on both windows and android. Thanks